# How to create Cross tab / matrix report in D365 for Product Type, Vendors , and few dimensions

Tags: matrix, report, axapta, crosstab, dynamics-365

I have a requirement to develop a cross tab or matrix report in D365 in traditional way.
I have to design a report that gives the summary of Qty, Price per unit, and Amount for product type based on the Vendors. Presuming the best design to be a cross tab report with columns displaying Product type and dimension and rows representing each vendor. Showed a small piece of example.

```
                         Column1                        Column2
                     Product Type 1                Product Type 2
                Qty | price per unit | Amount    Qty | price per unit | Amount 
 Row1  Vendor1
 Row2  Vendor2
```

Could any of you guide me on how to start to get the Cross tab report as above in D365 report.
I am unaware on how to proceed to develop this report. Any help provided will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Request you to go through the below link which will help you to gain the basic knowledge on how to create SSRS reports for D365. You can use Matrix template to create the report you mentioned.

https://readyxrm.blog/2018/07/24/how-to-create-your-first-dynamics-365-ssrs-report/

I do not have vendors entity available so I have used QuoteDetails entity for this sample as it also has multiple products attached to it. Below is the sample fetch I have used.

```
<fetch>
  <entity name="quote" >
    <attribute name="quoteid" />
    <attribute name="quotenumber" />
    <link-entity name="quotedetail" from="quoteid" to="quoteid" link-type="inner" alias="quotedetail" visible="true" >
      <attribute name="productname" />
      <attribute name="productidname" />
      <attribute name="producttypecode" />
      <attribute name="productnumber" />
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Also, attached is the gif on how to add a matrix and configure it the way you want it.[image]

If you found the answer helpful please mark it verified. Thanks